# Mac OS X 10.5+ and POSIX

Tags: macos, posix

I need to program an authentication module that has to work with Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard
and at the same time needs to be POSIX-compliant.

I read here: developer.apple.com/leopard/overview/osfoundations.html

that since Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard, Mac OS X is POSIX-compliant (to POSIX 1003.1),
but working under MAC OS X 10.5 Leopard myself, I can't find any trace of my user name
neither in /etc/passwd nor in its successor /etc/master.passwd, which is mentioned here: developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/passwd.5.html

Instead it says in both files OpenDirectory Service is used, which should be OpenLDAP
according to the OpenDirectoryService man-page.

Is this still POSIX-compliant ? I guess not. I wonder how Mac OS X would handle my 
100% POSIX-compliant code which depends on /etc/passwd ?

I would be gratefull if someone could explain the way this works to me.

Thank you for your time and trouble.

Best regards

Phil.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the way that users and passwords are stored is covered by POSIX (or at least by POSIX 1003.1) - look at the [POSIX Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) for a quick overview of what *is* covered.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `getpwuid` or `getpwnam` functions from `pwd.h` for searching of user name/ID. It is a part of the 1003.1 standard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like POSIX doesn't cover this, but *most* major Unices seem to use `PAM` these days.  You could try checking out how to authenticate users using PAM...